# How do I split a path file string in different parts and then print it out with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split, fs, indexof

I am working on a project for fun using IndexOf, splitting... and I am trying to get my code to print out the content before the ":" and after for each line. Instead I'm getting issues combining 2 pieces of code by going to each number of lines and splitting them. I’m looking for maybe a for/while loop so it grabs each part for each line and assigns it to the var (origin,color). (I eventually want to call var - origin,color in my later script.

I have tried looking around on guides but haven't found something to cement the 2 ideas together. Might be easy but Im just missing it...

EDIT: [From CODE 1]-

console.log(lines);

Gives:

[ 'Level1:Blue', 'Level2:Red', 'Level3:Green' ]

### CODE 1

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = 'file.txt';    

var text = fs.readFileSync(path).toString(); 

var lines = text.split('\n'); 

var newlines_count = lines.length;

var i=0; //looping through the lines

var count=1; //counts how many

var linechange=1;


for (; i < newlines_count; ) 

{

linechange = lines[i];

  console.log(lines);

  console.log(count);

  i++;

//counts how many lines in the string

}
```

---

### CODE 2

```
var str = "Level1:Blue";

var long=str.length;

var place=str.indexOf(":")

//console.log(place)

var origin=str.slice(0,place);

var color=str.slice(place+1,long);

console.log(origin);

console.log(color);

//splits the content before and after the ":"
//Code 2 Doesn't have the long string from Code 1 so the variable "long" wont really work
```

The info in the .txt file is(can be anything w/ ":"):

Level1:Blue

Level2:Red

Level3:Green

...(keeps going as I add more)

---

What I'm trying to get printed out:

Level1

Blue

Level2

Red

Level3

Green

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and join it with some linefeeds and make your output.

```js
function splitPrint(string) {
    var parts = string.split(':');
    console.log(parts.join('\n\n'));
}

splitPrint('Level1:Blue');
```

Output line for line

```js
function splitPrint(string) {
    var parts = string.split(':');
    parts.forEach(part => console.log(part));
}

splitPrint('Level1:Blue');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m new with Linefeeds. How would I split it into 2 variables as per code 2 (origin and color)? Could I use it with a for/while loop? With you answer, will I have to copy and paste each line from the .txt file into the parenthesis? I’m trying to grab each line of the .txt at a time

Comment: you could take a destructuring like `[left, right] = string.split(':');` which sets variables `left` to the value of index zero and `right` to the value at index one.

Comment: Ok. Like this, [origin,color] = lines.split(':'); ? How would you do it for each line? [origin,color] =lines.split(':').newlines_count ?

Comment: i am not shure how `lines` look like. please add an example (in the question, pref.)

Comment: I added what lines look like if printed out - near the top and above CODE 1

Comment: you could take `['Level1:Blue', 'Level2:Red', 'Level3:Green'].forEach(splitPrint);`.

Comment: Almost have it. I don't want that extra print out from "lines.forEach(splitPrint);". If I remove it, an error appears. I want to use "left" and "right" in a later code so thats why included it in the function. Here is all my code with your suggestions at the moment: https://pastebin.com/HHQicLhK

Comment: i have no idea.

Comment: Ok. Know any other methods to get it to work - getting “left” and “right” (with JavaScript)?

Comment: sorry, i have the general problem with your code. i don't get the purpose of it. it seems, you like to count lines and take an output of parts who are separates by new line and the lines by colon. what i dont get, is what you like to do after splitting the first (lines) level, before you like to print (hm, ... in the console) the values later. what is the overall thing, you like a acomplish?